# Cant find extensions on Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Hi this probably seems stupid because im new to it but im watching a JS tutorial and the guy downloads the Live Server extension from the VS Extension Marketplace. I cant find the marketplace in VS. I tried using CTRL + SHFT + x from a visual studio forum tutorial but nothing happened. I also tried downloading an extension from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/VSCode but I got a message saying 'You must have VS on your computer', even though I have VS 2022 installed. Does anyone know how I could fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You mention VSCode then say you have VS2022 installed. They are not the same thing.

Comment: I'm having trouble connecting to the VS Marketplace website, just now. Maybe it's a temporary break in the server, or something.

Comment: @dmoo Im using javascript and html inside Visual Studio 2022. Heres a screenshot: https://gyazo.com/db83bb0cadd0fc2f8e83cf47284274f6